# How can I prefix all column names in a T-SQL function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table T with 2 columns C1 and C2

I want a function that returns T but after prefixing all column names with "PREFIX_".

The prefix is a dynamic string passed to the function.

It is possible?

I want something like

```
SELECT C1 AS @prefix + 'C1', 
    C2 AS @prefix + 'C2' 
FROM T
```

Comment: Is the function that you want to write always running on the same table, or do you want to specify an arbitrary table?

Comment: I've requested an edit to your question to clarify that you're looking to change the column names, as opposed to values. As @Alex K. has pointed out below, some form of Dynamic SQL is the only way to return a resultset with varying/unknown schema. You can't use a function, but you could wrap the dynamic SQL in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it even when you don't know the columns already.

```
declare @prefix varchar(20)
declare @sqltext nvarchar(500)
set @prefix = 'prefix_'

declare @columnnames varchar(500)

select @columnnames = coalesce(@columnnames, '')+',' +column_name + ' '+ @prefix+column_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a where table_name = 't' and table_schema = 'dbo'

set @sqltext = 'select '+stuff(@columnnames,1,1,char(0))+' from t'

exec(@sqltext)
```

Comment: can I create a function to return the above result?

Comment: no, but you can make a stored procedure and redirect the result into a table. I don't see an advanage of using a function for this.

Comment: @Rohit it is only possible to solve your question using dynamic sql. Dynamic sql will not work in functions, you will have to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As its for a known number of columns you can construct the SQL string with the alias and `exec()` it;

```
declare @prefix varchar(32) = 'prefix_'
declare @sql    nvarchar(1024) 

set @sql = 'select C1 as [' + @prefix + 'C1], C2 as [' + @prefix + 'C2] from T'
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: can I return Table using exec ?

Comment: `exec` is not available within a function